# Running NginX and PHP (CGI) on Windows 10 - No input file specified

Tags: windows, php, nginx

I want to setup a web dev environment on my Windows 10 PC. On my 2nd hard drive (`D:\WebDev`) I have the following:

[image]

This is how my NginX is configured: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=JFSX6hfU

So, this is the contents of my **start.bat** file:

```
@ECHO OFF
set PATH=D:\WebDev\php-5.6.16;%PATH%

ECHO Starting...

RunHiddenConsole.exe D:\WebDev\php-5.6.16\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000
RunHiddenConsole.exe D:\WebDev\php-5.6.16\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9001
RunHiddenConsole.exe D:\WebDev\php-5.6.16\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9002
RunHiddenConsole.exe D:\WebDev\php-5.6.16\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9003
RunHiddenConsole.exe D:\WebDev\php-5.6.16\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9004

RunHiddenConsole.exe D:\WebDev\mariadb-10.1.9\bin\mysqld --defaults-file=D:\WebDev\mariadb-10.1.9\my.ini --standalone --console

cd D:\WebDev\nginx-1.9.7 && START /B nginx.exe && cd ..
```

> This was put together based on [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819351/can-windows-php-fpm-serve-multiple-simultaneous-requests/33032959#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819351/can-windows-php-fpm-serve-multiple-simultaneous-requests/33032959#_=_)

When I run `start.bat` file, NginX and MariaDB is getting started (i've verified by visiting `http://localhost` and I can see the `index.html` being served) and I can connect to the MariaDB Server (mysql) with Navicat.

The only thing that isn't working is the PHP. Firstly, I cannot see any PHP processes in the task manager and when I visit `phpinfo()` page, I get the error:

> No input file specified.

Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: You're calling `RunHiddenConsole.exe` but is your `start.bat` script in the same directory as `RunHiddenConsole.exe`? Note, also, you've `cd`'d into your nginx folder at the very end of your `start.bat`, you may need to CD into wherever `RunHiddenConsole.exe` is

Comment: Hi. See screenshot in the post. `RunHiddenConsole.exe` is in the same dir `start.bat` is in. It's working fine for mysqld. just not for php.

Comment: Yes, stupid me. My bad. Sorry!

Comment: No problem. I even tried to launch the php-cgi manually in cmd (single instance on port `9000`) and whilst it was running, I changed the nginx config and instead of using a upstream, explitly pointed to ip:port and started nginx to see if it works, it did not. Tested the same thing on windows 7 (works fine). I am running Avira antivirus, could this be blocking PHP somehow?

Comment: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows - to find out if anything else is listening on the ports you've defined...

Comment: I have checked now. Port `9000` -> `9004` was not in use. Just to be sure, I've changed the bat/nginx config to use port `19000` -> `19004` and tested, no joy :( I am on windows 10 x64 but the php binary is 32-bit (non-thread safe). Do i need to use 64-bit PHP?

Answer (score 1):

After seeing you `nginx.conf` file in link above, I think the problem is that you do not define `root` under `location ~ \.php$`, Since you root directory is same in different locations you can define it once under `server` section.

So
Edit `nginx.conf`
move line:

```
root   D:/WebDev/projects/localhost;
```

under

```
server {
```

Comment: Please explain this. Do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: As you see the questioner put a link to his `nginx.conf` file above, I tell him to edit it